# Dart FFI can't load dynamic library on Android

Tags: android, c++, flutter, dart, dart-ffi

I have a simple C++ function compiled into a `dylib` file that I'm trying to run on an Android phone. The function is super simple, it just adds to numbers and returns the result. However, I keep getting this error:
`Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'libadd.dylib': dlopen failed: library "libadd.dylib" not found` .

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've done the following steps:
My Dart implementation:

```
import 'dart:ffi' as ffi;
import 'dart:io' show Platform, Directory;

import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

typedef C_ADD = ffi.Int Function(
    ffi.Int a, ffi.Int b); // FFI signature of C function
typedef ADD = int Function(int a, int b);

void linkAndCallFunction() {
  var libraryPath = path.join(Directory.current.path, "libadd.dylib");
  final dylib = ffi.DynamicLibrary.open(libraryPath);

  final ADD add = dylib.lookup<ffi.NativeFunction<C_ADD>>("add").asFunction();
  final result = add(40, 2);
  print(result);
}
```

I've added these to the `build.gradle` files:
`build.gradle`:

```
buildscript{
    ext{
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
    }
    ...
```

and `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "../../lib/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
```

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(add LANGUAGES CXX C)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/lib")

add_library(add SHARED ./add.cpp)
```

and my file structure of the project looks like this:

```
   lib/
      - add.cpp
      - add.o
      - CMakeLists.txt
      - libadd.dylib
      - main.dart
```

it also may be worth mentioning that in order to compile `add.cpp` into a `dylib` I ran the following commands:

```
g++ -c add.cpp
ar rvs libadd.dylib add.o
```

and if you're wondering, `add.cpp` looks like this:

```
#define EXPORT extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default")))
__attribute__((used))

EXPORT
int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

Where is this error coming from? am I compiling to a dylib incorrectly?

Comment: You have a cmake file (implies Android) but you are trying to load a dylib (which implies macos). You've tagged the question android - so why a dylib? Why are you manually invoking g++? Can you explain more what you are doing - target os, flutter or pure dart?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8JD8hHkBMc

Comment: @RichardHeap I'm trying to write a couple of c++ functions for the backend of a project I'm working on, the frontend will be in Flutter. I'm realizing now that I need to run `cmake .` and `make` before I run the program, but since I'm using Mac those commands actually create a .dylib file, and when I run the program on a connected Android phone it still doesn't work. I want a static library instead that will be shipped with the app instead of compiling it at runtime. How would I even compile it to work on the Android phone? Also, do I have to initialize the flutter project as a plugin first?

Comment: I'd always do flutter ffi work in a plugin then depend the main project on the plugin. Nothing gets compiled at runtime - it gets compiled at build time - when you do flutter run or launch the debugger. Just because you are building *on* a mac, doesn't mean you should be compiling *for* the mac - you need to be compiling for android. Follow the steps in the video linked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this problem was relatively simple, it just stemmed from my lack of knowledge on how Android actually compiles to a static library. Hopefully it helps someone else who is trying to understand how to setup external C++ code in a flutter program.

The static library is generated automatically and is set up in CMakeLists.txt.

Firstly, I moved all the C++ files into the `android` folder. Then, I set up CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

add_library( add  // library name, will create libadd.so

            SHARED

            add.cpp

)
```

The problem before was that I was trying to manually compile the file myself, when I should have been letting CMakeLists do it instead. According to the android documentation:

"The convention CMake uses to name the file of your library is as follows:

`liblibrary-name.so`

For example, if you specify "native-lib" as the name of your shared library in the build script, CMake creates a file named libnative-lib.so. "
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake

So when I run the program, the static library is created automatically and placed in the correct place. Then, the Dart FFI can find it with the `DynamicLibrary.open()` function. In this case, CMakeLists will generate a file called `libadd.so`, and I can call`DynamicLibrary.open('libadd.so')` and the program works.